# iMacro - How to complete the same task on multiple url's

Tags: loops, google-chrome, macros, tcl

I want to download a csv from yahoo finance. I want to do this for a list of 200 companies. In tcl I can setup a procedural load, however I am unsure how to do this in iMacro. Would anyone please be able to help?

My iMacro code is shown below for the company AOP-

```
VERSION BUILD=1005 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/**AOP**.AX/history?p=**AOP**.AX&.tsrc=fin-srch

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:input ATTR=ID:yfin-usr-qry CONTENT=aop

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:11<SP>Jan<SP>2019<SP>-<SP>11<SP>Jan<SP>2020

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Max

ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>data
```

I then want to repeat the process for the company NCM-

```
URL GOTO=https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/**NCM**.AX/history?p=**NCM**.AX&.tsrc=fin-srch

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:input ATTR=ID:yfin-usr-qry CONTENT=aop

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:11<SP>Jan<SP>2019<SP>-<SP>11<SP>Jan<SP>2020

TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Max

ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES

TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>data
```

I am hoping to have one set of code where the company code variable is referenced from a list that is 200 or so long.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this (note the `%s` placeholders in the template URL):

```
set template {VERSION BUILD=1005 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://au.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%s.AX/history?p=%s.AX&.tsrc=fin-srch
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:input ATTR=ID:yfin-usr-qry CONTENT=aop
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:11<SP>Jan<SP>2019<SP>-<SP>11<SP>Jan<SP>2020
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Max
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>data}

set companies {AOP NCM ...}

foreach company $companies {
    set imacro_code [format $template $company $company]
    exec do_something_with $imacro_code
}
```